# Using <article> and <figure> within a <li> list

Tags: html, html-lists

After coding with XHTML for a number of years, I'm finally jumping into HTML5 to build a simple portfolio website.

The website I'm building displays 12 thumbnails on the homepage. When you rollover a thumbnail it displays a caption. Both the image and caption link to a post.

**The old XHTML way**

```
<div class="thumb">
<a href="portfolio_1" title="Portfolio item 1"><img width="225" height="150" src="images/thumb_1.jpg" alt="Portfolio item 1" /></a>
<h3><a href="portfolio_1" title="Portfolio item 1">Portfolio item 1</a></h3>
</div>
```

**The new way**

```
<ol>
<li class="thumb">
<article>    
<figure>
<a href="portfolio_1" title="Production test 8"><img width="225" height="150"   src="images/thumb_1.jpg" alt="Portfolio item 1" /></a>
<figcaption><a href="portfolio_1" title=""><h3>Portfolio item 1</h3></a></figcaption>
</figure>
</article>
</li>
</ol>
```

For the new code, I've used a list for each portfolio item. Within the list I've created an article and then used the figure tag for the image and image caption.

**My question**
Is this HTML5 semantic overkill? There's lots more code than the original XHTML version and I'm wondering whether it would be better to loose the list completely.

Looking forward to your feedback.

Comment: I think figure on itself is enough here, because there is no actual article – it’s more of a teaser, that only links to the actual article on another page.

Comment: Note that your 'old XHTML way' is completely valid HTML5.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I've found some great articles on HTML5. This really helped: http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element. #RockOn

Answer (score 0):

firstly, no need for the `article` tag; this is an image, not a block of text.

secondly, unless you have more than one list to style (besides your `nav li`) you won't need the class style, just your regular `ol li {}`, so no need to class the list.

lastly, i've just run a page through the W3.org validator and have been told that one cannot place a figure within an ordered list. no reasons are given, so i cannot say why, but as robertc says, your old XHTML method will work just fine, now and forever (just use the HTML5 doctype).

PS, when using HTML5 doctype your `img` tag could be simplified, with `figcaption` added to generate a searchable caption:

`figure`

```
<img src="images/cache.png" alt="alternative text">
    <figcaption>captionated text</figcaption>
```

`/figure`

Comment: I believe you can place it in an unordered list though, I tried I and it worked